# \adjustlimits on bracketed expression

Tags: math-mode

I have the expression

```
\sup_a \left\{ \inf_b f(a,b) \right\}
```

which renders as

[image]

If the braces `\left\{` and `\right\}` were not part of the expression, I could use `\adjustlimits` to ensure that the arguments in the supremum and infimum shared the same vertical position.

Is there a way to achieve the desired effect in this case?

Comment: just use `\{` and `\}` not `\left\{` and `\right\}` the over-sized braces are not helping here

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the comment. If you're suggesting `\adjustlimits \sup_a \{ \inf_b f(a,b) \}`, this also does not compile. If you're suggesting removing `\adjustlimits` altogether, that does not produce the desired effect.

Comment: No the `{}` comment was more of a side issue. I'm sure we have questions/answers on equalising the limits on operators with and without a descender, I'll see if I can find...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no hope of making `\adjustlimits` to work in this case.

The problem is twofold: “sup” has a descender, “inf” doesn't; “b” has an ascender, “a” hasn't.

So I give two solutions: in the first one I use a special “inf” with an artificial descender; in the second solution, I use a special “sup” with a smashed “p”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathOperator*{\infd}{inf\vphantom{\operator@font p}} % inf with descender
\DeclareMathOperator*{\supx}{su\smash{\operator@font p}} % sup without descender
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\sup_{a\vphantom{b}}\bigl\{\infd_{b} f(a,b)\bigr\}
\]

\[
\supx_{a\vphantom{b}}\bigl\{\inf_{b} f(a,b)\bigr\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh yes b isn't the same shape as a I forgot that:-)